# How to swap svg in React using a function?

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-component

I want to swap svg images. How to do it?

I add them to the React app:

```
import { ReactComponent as Paint } from '../style/ImagesGame/PaintBrush.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MagicWand } from '../style/ImagesGame/MagicWand.svg';

<Pain/>
<MagicWand/>
```

Please help me to swap pictures using the function

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Comment: @zero298 I didn't understand how this would help. If you know the answer please share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator) to switch between which SVG is displayed:

```
import { ReactComponent as Paint } from '../style/ImagesGame/PaintBrush.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MagicWand } from '../style/ImagesGame/MagicWand.svg';

const Foo = () => {
  const [paintMode, setPaintMode] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {paintMode ? (
          <Paint />
        ) : (
          <MagicWand/>
        )}
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setPaintMode((curr) => !curr)}>Toggle Mode</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```